# sap.viz.ui5.data.MeasureDefinition How to use format property

Tags: sapui5

Anyone know how to use format property in object `MeasureDefinition`.
The documentation describes:

- Format pattern for values of the measure
- Type: any

[API reference on `class sap.viz.ui5.data.MeasureDefinition`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.viz.ui5.data.MeasureDefinition)

I tried to add type for property: `value` in `MeasureDefintion`, but for custom type don't work properly (all value in vizFrame is 0).
I saw, that when change (in the custom type) decimal separator and thousand separator is the problem. Custom type extends [NumberFormat](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat%23methods).

Comment: @greybeard thanks for reply. I added more information.

Comment: (looks good now)